# Authenticate twitter bot with static secrets?

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetinvi

**My plan:**

I am writing a bot, that will send some tweets every now and then using the library tweetinvi (https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi).

The bot is currently using the access token and secret I generated in my developer console.

**The issue:**

The bot will send the tweets using my personal account now. That's why I created a new secondary account, that should be used for the tweets in the future.

But how can I authenticate the bot now?

1. The new account is not a developer account and I don't see any option to generate an access token and secret in the account settings.
2. Further more I don't think the usual oauth "click on the twitter icon and login to twitter" sign in is the right choice for my bot, because I don't have a website or browser session, just a program that runs wherever.

Can't I just create a some static sort of access token and a secret for my secondary account?

What would you suggest me to do, if that is not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create an access token and secret for your secondary account. The standard way to do this would be to implement sign-in with Twitter in an app, which would require a web backend.

There are a couple of alternative options:

1. You can use [`twurl`](https://github.com/twitter/twurl), which is a Twitter-provided command line tool. You’ll need to have Ruby installed, and then install `twurl`. Using `twurl` you can run

`twurl authorize --consumer-key [your API token] --consumer-secret [your API secret]`

This will then provide a URL you should open in your browser. Authenticate this to your secondary account and type the PIN into your terminal. The account token and secret will be placed in a hidden file called `.twurlrc` in your home directory, and you can use them for your bot in the same way you’re currently using your main account tokens.

2. You can use [another utility called tw-oob-oauth-cli](https://github.com/smaeda-ks/tw-oob-oauth-cli) to do the same thing. This is a bit easier as you don’t need to install Ruby, and can just download a Windows binary. You’ll want to rename the binary with a .exe extension.

`tw-oob-oauth.exe --key [your API token] --secret [your API secret]`

This will output the account token and secret on the terminal after you’ve been through the web flow.

Answer (score 1):

To authenticate via Tweetinvi you can follow the guide here : https://linvi.github.io/tweetinvi/dist/authentication/authentication.html

```cs
var appClient = new TwitterClient("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET");

// Start the authentication process
var authenticationRequest = await appClient.Auth.RequestAuthenticationUrlAsync();

// Go to the URL so that Twitter authenticates the user and gives him a PIN code.
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(authenticationRequest.AuthorizationURL)
{
    UseShellExecute = true
});

// Ask the user to enter the pin code given by Twitter
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the code and press enter.");
var pinCode = Console.ReadLine();

// With this pin code it is now possible to get the credentials back from Twitter
var userCredentials = await appClient.Auth.RequestCredentialsFromVerifierCodeAsync(pinCode, authenticationRequest);

// You can now save those credentials or use them as followed
var userClient = new TwitterClient(userCredentials);
var user = await userClient.Users.GetAuthenticatedUserAsync();

Console.WriteLine("Congratulation you have authenticated the user: " + user);
```